# Python IF , or logic returning wrong results

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a table with the following information

| No of transactions | GST | Item cost GST inclusive |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0.5 |

I wish to include an additonal column with the following logic

```
def incl(s):
    if ((s['No of Transactions'] ==0) & (s['GST'] ==0)):
        return s['Item Cost GST inclusive']
    else:
        return s['Item Cost GST inclusive']*0.9

df2['Item Cost GST exclusive'] = df2.apply(incl, axis=1)
```

I am getting the following table

| No of transactions | GST | Item cost GST inclusive | Item cost GST exclusive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0.5 | 0.45 |

Logically  when there is no GST, item cost GST inclusive does not get multlplied by 0.9, because there is no point in triggering the condition. Also generally in cases where 'no of transaction' is 0, there is no item cost at all.

I was expecting the following table

| No of transactions | GST | Item cost GST inclusive | Item cost GST exclusive |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0.5 | 0.5 |

I am not sure what went wrong in the logic. I am sure the logic is wrong.
Please help.

I will appreciate any kind suggestions please.

Comment: In Python use `and` not `&` for Boolean logic.

Comment: Thank you so much...Is it true for or as well?

Comment: Because `'No of transactions'` is not 0 but `'GST'` is 0, it does not meet the if condition, so you get 0.45. Is there a problem?

Comment: @Thierry That's not the issue.

Comment: Logically when there is no GST, item cost GST exclusive does not get multlplied by 0.9, because there is no point in triggering the condition. Also generally in cases where no of transaction is 0, there is no item cost at all. What is the mistake in the logic guys?

Comment: @Mechanic pig, I am slightly confused. I think or will not do the trick and 'and' is taking the first condition only. The correct condition Thretically, fisrt look into no if transaction , and if it is not 0 than look into GST to trigger the calculation.

Comment: @Mihan I think what you need is `or` instead of `and`. The former only requires one of the two conditions to be true, and the latter requires both to be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def incl(s):
    if ((s['No of Transactions'] ==0) or (s['GST'] ==0)):
        return s['Item Cost GST inclusive']
    else:
        return s['Item Cost GST inclusive']*0.9

df2['Item Cost GST exclusive'] = df2.apply(incl, axis=1)
```

This should do it.

Comment: might get a better idea, have a look at this 

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-and-and-in-python/#:~:text=and%20is%20a%20Logical%20AND,otherwise%20True%20when%20using%20logically.

Comment: That did not work.

Comment: could you share the data that you're working on?

Comment: my appologies. The data is confidential. But the problem is solved with 'or' as '@Mechanic suggested. Thank you so much for helping me out.